# lightning web component navigate to record edit page with default field value not work

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation

I have a action button which will navigate user to record edit page with a default field value setting.

```
const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
         Stage__c: 'Pending Requestor'             
     });
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
         type: 'standard__recordPage',
         attributes: {
             recordId:this.recId,
             objectApiName: objName,
             actionName: 'edit'
         },
         state: {
            defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,            
        }
     });
```

you can see that i want to pre-set stage field to be "Pending Requestor" when it navigate to record edit page.
Actually, when user navigate to record edit page, the stage field value is dsplayed as "Pending Requestor". but when i save this record without any update. this record was saved with stage equals "draft"(this is the old value). it seems that the defaultValues did not work.

I have no idea why it happen like this(default values displayed in field but not saved in record when save).

does any one has any idea about this?

update:
I did some test with different objects. it works for other custom objects. i have no idea which difference between these two custom objects.i have no idea what is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Hmm, if it works with the other objects, did you check the permissions on the Stage__c?

Comment: what type of field is stage? Do you have record types on that object?

Comment: i am system admin and i have permisison to this field. i can edit it manually from the layout.

Comment: stage field is a picklist field, i also tried other text field in this object. also not work. i have record type on this object, all record type have this field picklist value.

Comment: what are you passing within `defaultFieldValues`? Are you passing in a `recordTypeId`?

Comment: passing defaultfieldvalues is a picklsit field value. I already raised a case to salesforce and they confirmed this issue, but they are still doing the research.